# Is there a way to replace the root page of a MAUI app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, maui

I have some controls on a page in a Xamarin.Forms app that DO NOT WORK when navigating back to the page.  I can only "go back" to the page by navigating to the page outright (I'm using Prism to do this) and it works.

When transitioning to MAUI, I'm writing my own navigation service to replace Prism.  Everything works, except navigation to replace the first page and clear the navigation stack.  This is NOT App.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync() The page is the first page in the navigation stack.  Attempting to replace App.MainPage with a new page does not work.  Nothing happens if I do this.

Example navigation stack:
MainPage
Page1
Page2

Navigation stack after navigating to new root page:
MainPage (but new instance of page, not the original instance).  Remainder of navigation stack has been cleared.

Comment: **1)** *"Navigation stack after navigating to new root page: MainPage (but new instance of page, not the original instance). Remainder of navigation stack has been cleared."* Is this describing a **symptom**, or is it describing **desired behavior**?  **2)** Regardless, the way to replace root page is `((App)Application.Current).MainPage = new MyNewPage();`  But since you don't **show the code you tried**, I have no idea whether you tried that, or something else. Its certainly possible that you encountered a Maui bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but further testing shows that you can replace MainPage for Maui.

You CANNOT just assign a NavigationPage to MainPage.  This will work for the navigation and any logic in associated viewmodel will work, but the UI will be blank.

If you just assign a ContentPage to MainPage, everything works great.

Comment: You saved me going down a rabbit hole with this 